# Creating a hardware control server on a Beaglebone

Tags: python, linux, shell, service, beagleboneblack

my aim is to setup a beaglebone server as a network accessible terminal for hardware control. essentially I want a to setup the BBB to accept some form of standard commands and actuate some electronics.
the commands to parse are pseudo GCode based and will come off another network PC -The master, executing these and other commands in order, not from human input.

this question is about the right server/service architecture to set it up.
the options I thought of are

- Master SSHs to Slave and runs some regular Linux shell commands.
  the downsides I see with that is that each command is in a separate process and for timed actuation of the same pins I will have to deal with process communication and such - I'm not too comfortable with that. and I would expose too much of the slave's bbb system.
- setup some sort of python shell like a telnet service and parse the commands.
  but I lose all the benefits of ssh such as authentication and encryption (both are a must)
- something with webservices - which I know nothing about but if its the right architecture I'm willing to learn.

this seems like something which must have been done before many times and I dont want to reinvent the wheel. but I couldn't find simple examples.

- Both master and slave are connected to the same network over Ethernet.
- except authentication information the protocol can be stateless and each command is independent of the previous ones
- If I could incorporate MachineKit into the actuation part it would be awesome but not a must.
- I would assume its a standard task in industrial automation, and if so which protocol would be best?

I'm looking for architecture and other ideas to look at...
maybe I'm missing the obvious.

Comment: Unfortunately open ended architecture discussions are not appropriate for Stackoverflow. SO questions must be specific.

Comment: Telnet, SSH work with Buffer, hardware control required real time access. UDP server - client better things if you have `<1ms` processing time.